# How would I measure performance of Motion vs raspivid?

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, motion, raspivid

I'm new-ish to programing, and a total n00b to RPIs.  I have a RPI 3, with the raspicam V2, and I'm trying to figure out which app draws less resources, between Motion ( http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome ), and raspivid ( https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md ), when recording video.

Is there a known formula for this sort of comparison?  I'm trying to determine which give the best performance, and delivers the most real fps.

Thanks

Comment: Your best bet is just to try it and see! Set it up, run it, and use linux commands like `htop` to monitor CPU and RAM usage. I don't know much about video on Linux or RPi but I'm sure both motion and raspivid have options to display FPS. It would be great if you post your results so people have some idea of what's possible. Results will vary depending on OS and software versions, configurations etc etc

Comment: Thanks for the `htop` recommendation.  It's giving me 2-9% usage for `raspivid`, and 20%+ for `motion`.  Additionally, `raspivid` give nice smooth video, with no guess-work, or configuration.  Downsides, no motion detection, timestamp, or other options for `raspivid`.  It's purely, user managed video recording.  Also, `raspivid`, by default, produces "raw h264" (possibly technically inaccurate, but how I've seen it referenced), which most people will want to convert to a more common format/wrapper.